# Persistent App on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In my Android manifest, I have flagged my application as "persistent", so that it automatically restarts if it crashes, is less likely to be killed by the system, etc. I know that normal applications cannot use this setting, but I am working on a custom ROM, and I load my application into the priv-app folder, and so I am able to use it.

This works perfectly well on pre-Lollipop phones. However, when I load my APK onto an Android 5 phone, the "persistent" setting is no longer honoured. I can use 'dumpsys activity' to verify that my app is persistent on Android 4.4.4, but not on Android 5.0.

Is there some additional requirement for persistence in Android 5? I see that some system-supplied apps are still persistent, so it's not as if it's completely impossible. Thanks.

Comment: Is your app signed by the firmware's signing key? Perhaps they are now requiring that, rather than the app merely being pre-installed. Just a guess...

Comment: I'm not able to sign it. I wondered if that might be it too, but I have hunted through the source (on the excellent androidxref.com) and I can't find anything like that in there. If someone were able to prove that's the case, that'd be almost as good as fixing my problem because at least I could stop worrying about it!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I misunderstood the nature of the problem. The real problem was that I hadn't given the apk the selinux context permissions. I used chcon to copy the context from another file in priv-app and that sorted it out.